# mySQL insert syntax error with quote

Tags: php, mysql

I'm receive the following error below, I believe its do in part the quote that I have in the insert string `5'10 - (178cm)` in which is passed by the `$en['height']` variable. what's the best way to handle this error?

**Error:** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '10 - (178cm)', m_btype = 'Rather Not Say' at line 12

**this is the mysql insert:**

```
m_height = '".$en['height']."',
```

**table is set as:**

```
varchar(30) latin1_swedish_ci
```

Comment: Congratulations, you have potential mysql-injection.

Comment: I'm guessing that you're either using deprecated mysql_* queries, or not using parametrization right in mysqli/PDO, since you do not provide the rest of the code. Please convert your code to use PDO or mysqli, and bind the parameters into the query to take care of the quotes.

Comment: @kirilloid: not a potential one, it's confirmed... if there wasn't an injection problem, then the `'` in `5'10` wouldn't be causing a syntax error.

Comment: Someone needs to read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @MarcB Yes, maybe I'm wrong in exact wording.

Comment: All obvious issues aside, what did you think MySQL would make of `5'10 - (178cm)`?

Comment: In a varchar?nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is that you must "escape" strings before inputting them into SQL queries. Not doing that will allow people to alter your query by inputting quotes. Example if I input the following string:

```
'; select * from users; --
```

Its possible to execute SQL that you did not intend. The solution is to escape:

```
m_height = '".mysql_real_escape_string($en['height'])."',
```

Or better yet use a more up to date method of querying mysql such as PDO or mysqli functions.

Edit I also think you have a more general syntax error. Try this:

```
m_height = "'".mysql_real_escape_string($en['height'])."'",
```

Comment: would it be safe to do something like this `foreach ($_POST['add'] as $key => $value) $_POST['add'][$key] = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($value));`

Comment: Yes that seems okay to me. stripslashes is optional depending on whether or not magic quotes option is enabled in PHP.